# Truncate e-mail text string at the @ portion in excel

Tags: excel, url

I have a situation where I have email addresses but I need to extract the url's. For example I have the email address jsmith@acmecompany.com and I need to remove all the characters up to and including the @ sign leaving me with the url "acmecompany.com". I'd also like to add the "www" in front of the extracted text. Thanks :)

Comment: You're assuming that the mail server is also a web server; that's likely, but not guaranteed.  And if the address is "...@gmail.com", what good will the gmail.com URL do you?  You're also assuming that if "example.com" is valid, "www.example.com" is also valid; that's *definitely* not guaranteed.  (Perhaps your assumptions are valid in your specific situation.)

Answer (score 8):

Split a email address in half:

Username:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1)
```

Domain:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1)+1)
```

...the +/- 1 adds or removes the @ symbol

Comment: FWIW, the +1 in the domain formula actually caused it to include the @ symbol.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `FIND` to find the `@` sign, then `RIGHT` and `LEN` to get the portion you want.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the URLs valid, you could always tweak it to `="WWW."&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1)+1)`

Hot tip: This is also good for separating first and last names in a list separated by space or comma or whatever.